# jQuery - repeating each() for each() element but resetting between loops

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to perform an action on the first 4 elements of each group.

The problem I have is that it doesn't seem to reset the count when it iterates through the next group.

With this example, the first four items of each group should be red, but it only works on the first group, not the second... please help :)

**html**

```
<div class="group">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item">Item 6</div>
  <div class="item">Item 7</div>
</div>
<div class="group">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item">Item 6</div>
  <div class="item">Item 7</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var itemLimit = 4;
$('.group').each(function(){
  $('.item').each(function(index, value){
    if(index < itemLimit){
      $(value).addClass('red')
    }
  });
});
```

**css**

```
.red{
  color: red;
}
```

here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a4zja9th/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.item` `index` refers to the index of **all** those `.item` together<sup>*1*</sup>.

A **simpler variant** would be using `.find()` and the `:lt()` selector

```js
var itemLimit = 4;

$(".group").find(".item:lt("+itemLimit+")").addClass("red");
```

```css
.group{
  padding: 10px;
}
.red{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item">Item 6</div>
  <div class="item">Item 7</div>
</div>
<div class="group">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item">Item 6</div>
  <div class="item">Item 7</div>
</div>
```

Want to do more stuff than just an `.addClass()` ? Use `.each()` on your already filtered elements collection:

```
$(".group").find(".item:lt("+itemLimit+")").each(function() {
   // addClass
   // or whatever you want
});
```

---

***1)*** The above is how I'd do it... Now let's explain your issue:

```
// DON'T USE!! JUST FOR EXPLANATION:
$('.group').each(function() {
  $('.item').each(function(index, value) { // You're taking all .item from the DOM

    console.log($(this).index(), index);  // See the difference in console!

    if($(this).index() < itemLimit) {     // Using $(this).index();
      $(value).addClass('red')
    }
  });
});
```

...cause `index` is the index of every `.item` in the collection of **all** `.item`.
instead `$(this).index()` is the actual **index** of an `.item` **within** it's parent `.group`.

***[jsFiddle using `.index()` instead of `.each(index`][1]***

To **correctly refer** `.item`  **child of** (this) `.group` you could use instead `$('.item', this).each(` or `$(this).find(".item").each(`

```
var itemLimit = 4;

$('.group').each(function() {
  $('.item', this).each(function(index, value) {
    if(index < itemLimit) {
      $(value).addClass('red')
    }
  });
});
```

***[jsFiddle Fixed child reference](https://jsfiddle.net/a4zja9th/7/)***

Answer (score 1):

It's easy :) You need to look at children elements of your current group, 
because ".item" is broad selector :)
Here is a fiddle :  https://jsfiddle.net/a4zja9th/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="group">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item">Item 6</div>
  <div class="item">Item 7</div>
</div>
<div class="group">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item">Item 6</div>
  <div class="item">Item 7</div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.group{
  padding: 10px;
}
.red{
  color: red;
}
```

JavaScript(Jquery):

```
var itemLimit = 4;

$('.group').each(function(index,value){
  $(value).children(".item").each(function(index, value){
    if(index < itemLimit){
      $(value).addClass('red')
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that referring to a single class refers to all classes on the page, regardless of where they appear.  Instead look at the `children()` of each group (and you can refer to the class as well)

```
$('.group').each(function(){
  $(this).children('.item').each(function(index, value){
    if(index < itemLimit){
      $(value).addClass('red')
    }
  });
});
```